# Bokeh scatter plots not showing

Tags: python, html, flask, bokeh

I tried to make a flask app that gets a CSV file from the user, then fits my ML algorithm and finally shows two scatter plots.
Although I could show individual scatter plots via `Markup(file_html(plot_obj, CDN, "my plot")`, when I use `components(plot_obj)`, and `render_template` to show both of them together it does not show any of them. Also, I have no error in the console. 
I am able to upload the data, then run my algorithm and get the results in the console, however I still don't see the plots.

here is **my app.py**:

```
from prad_run import fit
from plots_anomalies import tsne_plot
from bokeh.resources import INLINE, CDN

from bokeh.plotting import figure

import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, render_template
from pr_run import fit
from plots import tsne_plot

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods = ['GET'])
def home():


    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def results():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']

        df = pd.read_csv(file)

        gold_label, df_pr = fit(df)

        y_pr = df_pr.loc[:, 'avg_score']
        X_tsne = df_pr.drop(columns='avg_score')

        tsne_value = plot(X_tsne)



        p_true = figure(title="Data with True Labels",plot_width=300, plot_height=300,)
        true_df = pd.DataFrame(data=tsne_value, columns=["v1", "v2"])
        colormap = {1: 'red', 0: 'green'}
        true_df['label'] = gold_label

        true_df["color"] = true_df['label'].map(lambda x: colormap[x])

        p_true.scatter(true_df['v1'], true_df['v2'], color=true_df['color'], fill_alpha=0.8, size=5)


        p_pr = figure(title="Predicted results",plot_width=300, plot_height=300)

        tsne_df = pd.DataFrame(data=tsne_value, columns=["v1", "v2"])
        tsne_df["pr"] = [1 if x > 0.115 else 0 for x in y_pr]
        colormap = {1: 'red', 0: 'green'}


        tsne_df['color'] = tsne_df['pr'].map(lambda x: colormap[x])
        print(tsne_df['color'].values)
        p_pr.scatter(tsne_df['v1'], tsne_df['v2'], color=tsne_df['color'], fill_alpha=0.8, size=7)
        js1, divs1 = components(p_true)
        js2, divs2 = components(p_pr)

        return render_template("home.html", js1=js1, divs1=divs1,js2=js2, divs2=divs2 )
```

In my **home.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<title>Python Flask File Upload Example</title>
<h2>Select a file to upload</h2>
<p>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul class=flashes>
        {% for message in messages %}
          <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
</p>
<form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="file" autocomplete="off" required>
        </p>
    </dl>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>


<meta charset="UTF-8">

   <head>
  <title>Figure examples</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
       <link
            href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link
            href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link
            href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-1.4.0.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
  {{ script|safe }}
 </head>

    <body>
<div style="width: 20%; display: inline-block;">
    {{ divs1 | safe }}
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    {{ js1 | safe }}
</div>

<div style="width: 20%; display: inline-block;">
    {{ divs2 | safe }}
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    {{ js2 | safe }}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `<script>` tags returned by `components` have to go in the `<head>` not `<body>`. Additionally, you don't need to load BokehJS from CDN multiple times as you are doing above.

You might also want to consider the newer [`json_items`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html?highlight=components#json-items) API for embedding, which can be simpler in many cases:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html?highlight=components#json-items

Comment: Thanks! I have modified my HTML file and put the <script> tags on <head>, but still, it does not show the plots. I have used json_items but I found another issue which is regarding the file that I upload, I have the following function on my app.
py

Comment: I don't really understand your comment re: `json_items` and in any case can't say anything more offhand. If you update your example to be *minimal* (remove unrelated code) and *complete* (can be run by others, uses sythetic fake data, etc) then I am happy to investigate further.

Comment: Sorry for the issue in my comments. Because of the limited character, I couldn't paste my code. I used jason_items for making two separate plots. but I am receiving an HTTP request error. Is there any way to use ```jason_items``` API for embedding multiple plots at the same time, instead of making different @routes?

Comment: @sasha did you figure out how to show the plots? Would appreciate if you are able to share result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the reason that my plots did not display was using Conda environment. If you use Bokeh and Flask I encourage you to use virtualenv in the same folder that you are making your app instead of creating Conda environment.

Comment: I use Bokeh and conda daily since both were created in 2012. There may indeed be a local issue with your configuration (most likely: you had some things installed in a different env without realizing it) but that's not a reason to dispense a sweeping claim.